# Why file_get_contents() returns "Application Error"?

Tags: php, web-services, json

I have a simple code:

```
$t = file_get_contents("http://sub.example.com/list?u=test&passw=12345");
```

If I print that result I get "Application Error" text.

I really don't understand the reason, if I try to open that url on the browser i see it perfectly.

It returns "application/json" data.

Comment: my be the url returns that....

Answer (score 2):

It is possible that the web application at `sub.example.com` expects some additional input apart from what goes into the URL (e.g. a cookie), does not find this input, and errors out.

In any case, it's certain that the HTTP requests generated by (a) your program and (b) your browser are *not* identical, otherwise the application would exhibit the same behavior in both cases.

To debug this, you can do the following:

- Rewrite the code to use [`cURL`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) instead of `file_get_contents`, so that you can specify an HTTP proxy
- Install [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/), a fantastic HTTP debugging proxy
- Pass the HTTP request your application generates and one given manually through the browser through Fiddler
- Find the differences (you can simply do a text compare on the requests), this will lead you to the answer

Comment: exactly...so what can I do? DO i have to ad an user agent? (to seem like a browser?

Comment: @Dail: First you have to find all the differences between the HTTP requests, then examine them one by one. Unless you have some specific knowledge of the target application, which should help you zero in on the problem more easily.

Comment: you can specify any headers, including proxy, by passing a stream context to `file_get_contents`.

Comment: @Gordon: Thank you for the tip. I have never needed to use a stream context so far, so that approach was under my radar.